# Custom callback on user_register_form Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I have called a custom function on form submit of Drupal User Registration.

Below are the functions that i implemented

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function voen_registration_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //dpm($form);
  switch($form_id){
    case 'user_register_form':
      $form['account']['name']['#required'] = FALSE;
      $form['account']['name']['#type'] = 'hidden';
      array_unshift($form['#submit'],'voen_generate_username');
      print_r($form);
      break;
  }     
}

function voen_generate_username(&$form, &$form_state){
  //drupal_set_message('Function Running');
  die('Wokring');  
}
```

Now, when the form is submitted i print_r the $form and in submit key i get the following result which is what i expect

```
 [#submit] => Array
        (
            [0] => voen_generate_username
            [1] => user_register_submit
        )
```

But I don't know why my custom function is not executing. I tried with die() as well se drupal_set_message() and also tried to print_r() in custom function but no response. It is still giving me error of 'Please Enter Username' which is comming from user_register_submit function from user module.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The submit function is not executed because the validation function is not passed.
Take a look at `$form['#validate']`, there is an "user_account_form_validate" function which will not pass if you not define at least a default value for name field.

Anyway, if you're trying to allow registration only by email take a look at this module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration

Comment: Your reply seems true but is there any option that i can use within the same code. I mean there are some other fixes also in the registration form that is why i am avoiding any contributed module.

Comment: If you see the first line i set the #required attribute to False. This should work ? Just asking.

Comment: #required will be ignored, see: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_account_form_validate/7 .

If you still want to ignore this validation, just unset/replace this function from validate, and add a simplified function based on user_account_form_validate.